# Keynote to DVD?

Tags: dvd, cross-platform, iwork-keynote

Is there away to burn a Keynote presentation to a DVD that will work in DVD players and PC's? I'm using Keynote 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly quick way would be to export the slideshow as a quicktime movie and then create the DVD in iDVD.